# How to compare json object with a string?

Tags: javascript, json, testing, jasmine, protractor

I am making a API call which will return **JSON** in the body and I want to compare **JSON** object with a **String**. How can I do that?

API `res.body` returns following JSON object:

```
{
    "name": "tenant_tree",
    "documents": [
        {
            "tags": [],
            "scope": "all",
            "tenant_id": "0",   
            "id": "9dd2c5a5-2de2-4ac8-b195-04290f83b6fb",
            "version": 1,     
            "description": "",
            "name": "0",
            "grouping": "",
            "perm_read": "all",
            "perm_write": "all",
            "version_author": "dg",
            "version_date": 1470324147050,
            "is_current": true,
            "dependencies_guid": [""],
            "dependencies_name": [""],
            "display_name": "system"
        },
 }
```

I want to compare something like `expect(res.body).toMatch('"name": "0"');`  but this fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am able to compare json values in the API response body by:

`expect(res.body.name).toEqual("0")`

No need of parsing the response.

Refereed link  : [JSON.Parse,'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19239217/json-parse-uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-o)

Answer (score 4):

Don't use string comparisons or substring in a string checks here. You are dealing with JSON which has structure and its own syntax rules. Compare *objects* instead. Here is how you can check the value corresponding to the `name` key:

```
var obj = JSON.parse(res.body);
expect(obj.name).toEqual("0");
```

Also, `jasmine-matchers` package has some [advanced object matchers](https://github.com/JamieMason/Jasmine-Matchers#objects), check them out.

Comment: Hi @alecxe  `JSON.parse(res.body)` gives me error `Unexpected token o` and I tried   `JSON.stringify(res.body)` which gives me error : `undefined to equal 0`